# Displaying data from while loop into html code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need tips or direction on how can I display data from mysql using `echo`. But I want to display it in `html` code. I want to display `$row["title"]` of first title in mysql instead `title1` and `$row["content"]` of first content in mysql instead `content1` and do that for all 3 divs. `php` code works fine I just can't figure out how to make that possible.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" style="background-size:cover;">
<div class="item active">
    <img src="img/road1.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>title1</h2>
        <p>content1</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="img/road2.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>title2</h2>
        <p>content2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="img/road3.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>title3</h2>
        <p>content3</p>
    </div>
</div>-->
```

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<h2>" . $row["title"] . "</h2>";
        echo "<p>" . $row["content"] . "</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: And you also wants images to be different in all the three `div`??

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I'll try to do images by myself because it applies same logic if I'm not wrong. @tadman thanks for advice, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just move the html into the echo of the while loop.

```
echo '<div class="carousel-inner" style="background-size:cover;">';

$counter = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '
    <div class="item ' . ($counter == 1 ? 'active' : '') . '">
        <img src="img/road{$counter}.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2>' . $row["title"] . '</h2>
            <p>' . $row["content"] . '</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
    $counter++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

The only issue is the image, realistically you'd save the image in the database with the title and content then use the same method but for this simple case lets just use a counter

Comment: Thanks. Did some editing in my code and worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

please note that I change your entire code a little bit to make the desired results...

```
<div class="carousel-inner" style="background-size:cover;">

<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/road1.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $row["content"]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Also note that I'm repeating just the first image... You need an extra on planning to determine how to handle images in code and then update this one.